# Performance issue on CLOB column

Tags: oracle11g

I’m facing one issue with a table which has CLOB column.

The table is just a 15column table with one column as CLOB.

When i do SELECT on the table excluding CLOB column,  it take only 15min, but if i include this column the SELECT query runs for 2hrs.

Have check the plan and found both the query with and without COLUM uses same Plan.

```
| Id  | Operation                          | Name                      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                   |                           |   330K|    61M|   147K  (1)| 00:29:34 |       |       |
|   1 |  PARTITION RANGE ALL               |                           |   330K|    61M|   147K  (1)| 00:29:34 |     1 |    50 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID| CC_CONSUMER_EV_PRFL       |   330K|    61M|   147K  (1)| 00:29:34 |     1 |    50 |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                | CC_CON_EV_P_EV_TYPE_BTIDX |   337K|       |   811   (1)| 00:00:10 |     1 |    50 |
```

Below are the stats i collected.

```
Stats                                 Without CLOB Column       With CLOB Column 
recursive calls                               0                 1
db block gets                                 0                 0
consistent gets                               1374615           3131269
physical reads                                103874            1042358
redo size                                     0                   0
bytes sent via SQL*Net to client              449499347         3209044367
bytes received via SQL*Net from client      1148445             1288482930
SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client           104373              2215166
sorts (memory)       
sorts (disk)         
rows processed                              1565567             1565567
```

I'm planing to perform below, is it worth to try?
1) Gather stats on the table and retry
2) compress the table and retry

Comment: What client program do you use? (I assume SQL*Plus, but please confirm.)

Comment: Reading CLOB data _is_ expensive in Oracle. Are those CLOBs stored with "basicfile" or "securefile" storage? If it's `basicfile` you can probably improve performance when you switch to `securefile`. `basicfile` also suffers from a huge transactional overhead, so maybe cleaning up the LOB segment already helps. See the manual for details

Comment: Thanks for reply. not sure how to check Basicfile and Securefile.  below is the details i could see from the table structure.    LOB(EVENT_DETAIL_DATA_NEW) STORE AS SYS_LOB_P61
    (
      ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW
      CHUNK 8192
      NOCACHE LOGGING
      TABLESPACE TS_PRFLMART_TBL_2012
      STORAGE
      (
        INITIAL 8M
        NEXT 1M
        MINEXTENTS 1
        MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
        FREELISTS 1
        FREELIST GROUPS 1
        BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
      )
    )